# Spring Boot , JNDI lookup database with application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi

I create a REST service with Jersey , Spring Boot and Spring Data.

My setup is Java 1.8 , Maven 3.3.9 , Spring Framework 4.3.0.RELEASE , Jersey 2.23.1 , Spring Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE , javax.ws.rs-api 2.0.1 ,
Hibernate 5.1.0.FINAL

I try to build a DataSource via defining it in `context.xml` and referencing this in `application.properties`. See method `permDbJpaDataSource()`.
But it seems that the entry `spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/permDb` is ignored. A bean named `permDbJpaDataSourceFAIL` is created, but
all the properties are null (database URL, DB user etc...). I can see that the file `application.properties` is evaluated, because of
`spring.main.banner-mode=off` .

The method `jndiDataSource()` works fine, and I can build my application this way. But I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong
or if it's a bug.

These are my sources:

```
├───java
│   └───com
│       └───pkg
│           └───permDb
│               └───service
│                   │   PermDbServiceApplication.java
│                   │
│                   ├───services
│                   │       PermDbOwsService.java
│                   │
│                   └───springBoot
│                           PermDbJerseyConfig.java
│                           PermDbServiceSpringBoot.java
│
├───resources
│   │   application.properties
│   │   log4j2.xml
│   │
│   └───META-INF
│           context.xml
│
└───webapp
```

**PermDbServiceApplication.java**

```
package com.pkg.permDb.service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PermDbServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    //private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PermDbServiceApplication.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(PermDbServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(PermDbServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**PermDbServiceSpringBoot.java**

```
package com.pkg.permDb.service.springBoot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.persistence.SharedCacheMode;
import javax.persistence.ValidationMode;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = false)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pkg.permDb.repositories")
public class PermDbServiceSpringBoot
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PermDbServiceSpringBoot.class.getName());

    @Bean(name = "permDbEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean permDbEntityManagerFactoryBean() throws
            IOException
    {
        //Properties dmProps = dmProperties();
        Map<String, Object> propsMap = new Hashtable<>();

        logger.debug("erzeuge Bean {} ...", LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class.getName());
        logger.debug("DataSource: {}", jndiDataSource());
        //propsMap.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action",
        //        dmProps.getProperty("dm.hibernateDbSchemaGeneration"));

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        //hibAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(dmProps.getProperty("dm.hibernateDbDialect"));
        hibAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibAdapter);
        factoryBean.setDataSource(jndiDataSource());
        //factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(dmProps.getProperty("dm.userDbModel"));
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.pkg.permDb.entities");
        factoryBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
        factoryBean.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("PermDb");

        factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propsMap);

        logger.debug("Bean erzeugt: {}", factoryBean);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "permDbJpaDataSource")
    public DataSource permDbJpaDataSource() throws DataSourceLookupFailureException, IOException
    {
    /* ##############################
       when these lines are executed, the entry spring.datasource.jndi-name
       from application.properties is not evaluated
       ############################## */

        logger.debug("erzeuge Bean {} ...", DataSource.class.getName());
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        String dataSourceName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/permDb";
        DataSource dataSource = lookup.getDataSource(dataSourceName);

        logger.debug("Bean erzeugt: {}", dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name ="permDbJpaDataSourceFAIL")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource()
    {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/permDb");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        try
        {
            bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            logger.error("FEHLER: ", e);
        }
        return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "permDbTransactionManager")
    //@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(permDbEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

}
```

**PermDbJerseyConfig.java**

```
package com.pkg.permDb.service.springBoot;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.pkg.permDb.service.services.PermDbOwsService;

@Component
public class PermDbJerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PermDbJerseyConfig.class.getName());

    public PermDbJerseyConfig()
    {
        logger.debug("register services");
        register(PermDbOwsService.class);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/permDb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.main.banner-mode=off
#spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/permDb" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://my.server.de:5432/oaktree"
              username="uhtred" password="password" maxTotal="50" maxIdle="10"
              maxWaitMillis="-1"/>

</Context>
```

**pom.xml for module permDbService**, parent see below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>permDb</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.permDb</groupId>
        <version>0.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>permDbService</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.permDb</groupId>
            <artifactId>permDbRepositories</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <!--<version>9.4.1208</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- ###################   LOGGING   ####################-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
                <dependency>
                    &lt;!&ndash; dies wird benötigt, damit das Hibernate-Logging über log4j2 konfigurierbar ist&ndash;&gt;
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j.adapters</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**parent pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.permDb</groupId>
    <artifactId>permDb</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>mavenToolParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>permDbData</module>
        <module>permDbService</module>
        <module>permDbRepositories</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- zum timestamp siehe http://rterp.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/stamping-version-number-and-build-time-in-properties-file-with-maven/ -->
        <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <log4j.version>2.6.1</log4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>permDb-local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>permDb-ref</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/context.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <!--<filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>-->
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                                <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>context.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven-3</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.3.9</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j.adapters</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>LATEST</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <!-- dies wird benötigt, damit das Hibernate-Logging über log4j2 konfigurierbar ist-->
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.1208</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ows</groupId>
                <artifactId>owsMisc</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- #################   TEST   ################# -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

**UPDTAE**

This is the output when I start the applcation:

```
2016-07-28 11:31:03.802  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] d.lgn.permDb.service.PermDbServiceApplication  : Starting PermDbServiceApplication on GLL-H3-W7P139 with PID 5636 (D:\catalina-base-idea\webapps\permDb\WEB-INF\classes\com\pkg\permDb\service\PermDbServiceApplication.class started by ulrich.knaack in D:\Programme\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\bin)
2016-07-28 11:31:03.818  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] d.lgn.permDb.service.PermDbServiceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-28 11:31:03.880  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@410bf06: startup date [Thu Jul 28 11:31:03 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-28 11:31:05.175  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-07-28 11:31:05.284  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fbaaf65b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-28 11:31:05.331  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1451 ms
11:31:05.627 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG PermDbJerseyConfig - register services
2016-07-28 11:31:05.830  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] b.a.w.TomcatWebSocketContainerCustomizer : NonEmbeddedServletContainerFactory detected. Websockets support should be native so this normally is not a problem.
2016-07-28 11:31:05.861  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 11:31:05.861  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 11:31:05.861  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 11:31:05.861  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'com.pkg.permDb.service.springBoot.PermDbJerseyConfig' to [/*]
11:31:05.877 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG PermDbServiceSpringBoot - erzeuge Bean org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ...
11:31:05.877 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG PermDbServiceSpringBoot - erzeuge Bean javax.sql.DataSource ...
11:31:05.877 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG PermDbServiceSpringBoot - Bean erzeugt: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@49f798a4
11:31:05.986 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG PermDbServiceSpringBoot - DataSource: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@49f798a4
11:31:06.017 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG PermDbServiceSpringBoot - Bean erzeugt: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@439cc9b9
2016-07-28 11:31:06.033  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'PermDb'
2016-07-28 11:31:06.049  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: PermDb
    ...]
2016-07-28 11:31:06.205  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-07-28 11:31:06.205  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-07-28 11:31:06.205  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-07-28 11:31:06.501  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-07-28 11:31:06.891  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2016-07-28 11:31:06.906  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-07-28 11:31:07.187  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-07-28 11:31:08.388  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-28 11:31:08.404  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'permDbJpaDataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-07-28 11:31:08.404  INFO 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'permDbJpaDataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2:name=permDbJpaDataSource,type=BasicDataSource]
2016-07-28 11:31:08.420 ERROR 5636 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@49f798a4] with key 'permDbJpaDataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/permDb,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/permDb"
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Where are you deploying your application? You seem to be trying to configure a JNDI entry for a DataSource and then consume it from JNDI. Why not just configure it directly in application.properties and simplify things by removing JNDI from the picture?

Comment: by now, I'm deploying it in IntelliJ IDEA internally. Yes, I thought about defining all the parameters in `application.properties` . But I would like to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: I've made an edit to the method `permDbDataSource()` in `PermDbServiceSpringBoot.java`. Now it shows the code I've tried.